Derivative of an operator exponential.

The image is from the book Lie group  by Bryan Hall.
Question. There is some book where 5.10 is valid for operators? for example, I need 5.10 for $X=x$ (multiplication operator by $x$) and $Y=\partial_x$ (differentiation operator).

Yes, the formula is also valid for operators, given that they belong to a Lie algebra, but your case corresponds to the Heisenberg-Weyl algebra. Here is the most general formula : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Derivative_of_the_exponential_map#Statement

Yes. The Heisenberg-Weyl algebra (matrix) is the set of all matrix $\begin{bmatrix} 0 & 0 & 0\ q & 0 & 0\ t & p & 0\end{bmatrix}$. An representation is $tI+qx+p\partial_x$.

@Abezhiko Heisenberg-Weyl $\neq$ Heisenberg Lie algebra?

Those are indeed two different concepts, but the Heisenberg-Weyl algebra I was referring to can be represented by the matrices or the operators you pointed out. Don't bother too much, you can go straightforwardly with the computations. I'll write a small answer for you.

In the present case, you can "cheat" by applying Glauber formula before differentiating. Indeed, since $X = x$ and $Y = \partial_x$ commute with their (scalar) commutator, namely $[X,Y] = -1$, Glauber formula allows us to write :
$$
f(t) = e^{X+tY} = e^X e^{tY} e^{-\frac{t}{2}[X,Y]} = e^X e^{tY} e^{t/2},
$$
hence $f'(t) = e^X e^{tY} e^{t/2} (Y + \frac{1}{2})$ and finally $f'(0) = e^X (Y + \frac{1}{2}) = e^x (\partial_x + \frac{1}{2})$.
This result may be rederived in a more general context, starting from the derivative of the exponential map, i.e.
$$
\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}t} e^{Z(t)} = e^Z \phi(-\mathrm{ad}_Z) \dot{Z}, 
\quad\mathrm{with}\quad 
\phi(x) = \frac{e^x-1}{x} = \sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{x^k}{(k+1)!}.
$$
When $Z(t) = X + tY$, where $X,Y$ are time-independent, it is simplified to
$$
\left.\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}t} e^{X+tY}\right|_{t=0} = e^X \phi(-\mathrm{ad}_X) Y,
$$
because $\mathrm{ad}_YY = 0$. Now, given that the commutator $\mathrm{ad}_XY = -1$ is scalar when $X = x$ and $Y = \partial_x$, the Taylor expansion of $\phi$ is cut after the second term, i.e. $\phi(-\mathrm{ad}_X)Y = Y - \frac{1}{2}[X,Y] = Y + \frac{1}{2}$, hence
$$
\left.\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}t} e^{X+tY}\right|_{t=0} = e^X \left(Y + \frac{1}{2}\right) = e^x \left(\partial_x + \frac{1}{2}\right)
$$
in the end.
